# Bug in pscircle? Mismatched radius for thicker line

Tags: miktex, pstricks

for a simple pscircle I get a mismatched radius for thicker line. The small red circle in the left picture shows the mismatch with linewidth=1pt. In the right picture the small green circle shows that there is no mismatch for linewidth=0.5pt. I already see this deviation in dvi (with yap) and also in ps and pdf file. Please see the following minimal example (compiled with latex.exe under miktex 64bit): [image: minimal example]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.7cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.3,-1.3)(2.0,1.45)%
\psaxes[labels=all,ticks=all,linewidth=1.0pt]{->}(0,0)(-1.3,-1.3)(1.3,1.3)[$Re\{z\}$,0][{$Im\{z\}$},0]%
\pscircle[linewidth=1pt](0.0,0.0){1.0}%<- problem is here
\pscircle[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red](1,0.0){0.2}%
\rput[br]{0}(2.0,-1.3){linewidth=1pt}%
%\psframe[linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=red](-1.3,-1.3)(2.0,1.45)% Frame of pspicture
\end{pspicture}%
%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.3,-1.3)(2.0,1.45)%
\psaxes[labels=all,ticks=all,linewidth=1.0pt]{->}(0,0)(-1.3,-1.3)(1.3,1.3)[$Re\{z\}$,0][{$Im\{z\}$},0]%
\pscircle[linewidth=0.5pt](0.0,0.0){1.0}%
\pscircle[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=green](1,0.0){0.2}%
\rput[br]{0}(2.0,-1.3){linewidth=0.5pt}%
%\psframe[linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=red](-1.3,-1.3)(2.0,1.45)% Frame of pspicture
\end{pspicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
    \pscircle[linewidth=1pt,dimen=middle](0.0,0.0){1.0}%<- problem was here
```

Will be fixed in next upload to CTAN.